# Quiz app, how to add 1 when user choses A or B with a Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift

I have a quiz type app when you can chose A or B. I want to +1 to the score of A or B when the user has finished the app (for example they chose 14 A and 12 B). I'm trying to achieve this with a segmented control however nothing adds to the score. I was thinking maybe I should use buttons but I don't want the user to press the button twice and add +2 to the score only 1 per question.

Please see my code below and suggest what I can do, thanks!

[image]

```
func personalityTypeCalculator() {
    if cell.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        E + 1
    } else {
        if cell.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            I + 1
        } else {
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Copy and paste actual relevant code into your question.

Comment: Okay sure. I posted an image to show what was happening on screen. Thank you

Comment: @EAZYE Edit your question with the code of you `cellForRow` method

Answer (score 1):

**Your issue:**

You are not incrementing the value. The result of `E+1` is not actually saved in the variable. You should do `e = e + 1`, or shorter `e += 1`

**Some extra comments about your code:**

1. Don't capitalize your variable names
2. It's cleaner to use `switch` instead of multiple if-else statements:

```
switch cell.segementedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0: e += 1
    case 1: i += 1    
    default: break
}
```

3. `segementedController` is not really a controller, right? Name it accordingly: `segementedControl` or something more specific.

Comment: You're right about the += 1 part. However even tapping the segmented control crashes my app

Comment: Does your funcition actually get called? Put a breakpoint on it's first line and check. Also edit your question to show how you tie `segmentedControl` with the function. Are you using `addTarget:action` somewhere?

Comment: Hi, I have a custom Cell. I have made an outlet of the segmentedControl there and in my tableViewController file I've done    var cell = TableViewCell(). Whenever I try and execute the function I get this http://imgur.com/eM1yGK5 fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Have you implemented a line similar to that shown in the Overview section here? https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol  Perhaps you never properly assigned the selector - you did not provide enough code to be able to tell.

Comment: @EAZYE Hmm, It looks like you need the Cell to have a reference to your segmented control AND your VC to have a reference to your Cell. One of those appears to be missing. Set a breakpoint at that line, which will pause it before the line executes. You can then check the memory hierarchy, find the "cell" property under "self", and see if it is nil, or if the "segmentedController" property under "cell" is nil.

Comment: @EAZYE You should provide your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method so that we can tell what is your error. I suppose you don't deque the cell and thus segmentedControl is not initialized if you just call initializer like TableViewCell()

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're missing a reference, either to this cell, or to the segmented control. Add a breakpoint to the line you are crashing on so you can see the memory at that point. A window will appear at the bottom of Xcode similar to this: [image]  If you only have the console output, click the button highlighted in the bottom right corner to open the memory stack as well.

Expand the "self" item, and find "cell".  If it has a nil value, you need to make sure you're storing the reference to this cell when you instantiate it. If cell has a memory address, but you expand it and "segmentedControl" is nil, you need to make sure to store the reference to your segmentedControl on the Cell.

Additionally, it'd be best if you set up an action with a sender id, which will be the segmentedControl, so you don't need to worry about references like this.  `segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "action:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)`

Basically, replace `"action:"` with `"personalityTypeCalculator:"`, and pass in `sender` with type `id` to the function. Cast `sender` to type `UISegmentedControl, since you know that's what's triggering the action, and you can access the`selectedSegment` property from there.

Comment: Hi dude thanks for helping out. I think my problem is because the segmentedControl outlet is in the Custom Cell class and Im trying to make the magic work in the TableView Class, thats why Im doing var cell = TableViewCell() . Whats the right way of doing thing this? I made an action in both the tableview then tried in the cell but neither worked.                    When it was an action in the tableView I got this:  *also segmentedControl was nil and the cell has a memory address

Comment: It sounds like you're making your `cell` property reference a new, separate instance of the Cell. What you want to do is set that cell property to be a reference to the specific cell that you create in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. It will then also properly reference the segmentedControl.  This does not work as well if you have multiple similar cells, though. It only works properly if you have a single cell with this segmented control on it. Otherwise, you'll need to pass the sender as I mentioned, and add an identifier to the segmentedControl so you know which answer is being updated.

Comment: Hi again sorry for being pretty useless. What you were saying above, should I just be creating an action for the segmented control? How do I reference the segmented control outlet when trying to += 1 to the score, depending on the case? Ive got this     @IBAction func calculate(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        switch cell.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0: e += 1
        case 1: i += 1
        default: break
        }
    } BTW I think you are correct in what you're saying. Thank you again

Comment: So, if you set a IBAction from the prototype cell on your storyboard, every single cell with the same identifier is going to have the segmented control fire the same exact IBAction. You'll want to add an identifier / tag to the segmented control, usually by #define <constant name> <constant value> (that's obj-c) with constant value being an int. You could set this as an identifier or a tag. Tag will probably work better. Then have a switch case checking the tag of the sender, and updating the appropriate value. You set the tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: What I had described in my answer is adding a specific selector to the segmentedControl. IBAction means something interacts with the Interface Builder (your storyboard or .xib).  Anything you do via IBAction can also be done programmatically. `setSelector:` is the equivalent of setting an IBOutletConnection for an IBAction. You'd probably still want to set a tag, but this is nice because it's easier to set the specific functionality of similar components within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`